# Is there any alternative for $http from angular to Framework7?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-framework-7

I'm trying to implementing my POST REST API call in Framework7, problem is when i make a login call with $http in angular it is working, where as here i can't able to make the Login API call using Framework7 methods like post, ajax etc.,

Is there any possible replacement for $http in Framework7?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: It's plain old Javascript right? Lot's of different HTTP libraries about.

Comment: I can't get you exactly!

Comment: The answer is "yes". would you accept that?

Comment: Eventually no. I tried with different HTTP libraries but no use. If you still say "yes" give me some HTTP library methods except post, ajax, getJSON, get i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Framework7 docs](https://framework7.io/docs/dom.html) for the ***$$.get()*** method.

```
var $$ = window.Dom7;

$$.get('blog-post.php', {foo:'bar', id:5}, function (data) {
  $$('.articles').html(data);
  console.log('Load was performed');
});
```

That's probably the best way to go for you, and there are also the options of ***$$.post()*** or ***$$.getJSON***.

It might also be worth noting that the author of [this article](http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/) seems to think [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is the new standard for network requests in JavaScript.

You could just import your own networking library such as [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch).

Comment: Can we import and use JQuery related libraries like importing $http contained library will solve my problem to make use of $http.post

Comment: $http is from the AngularJS library, not JQuery. You could import JQuery and use something like `$.get`.

Comment: I just included angular.min.js into my project. Where do i initialize $http now. I'm using basic Framework7 structure to implement this. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You must inject $http into either an AngularJS controller or service. I'm not sure if AngularJS and Framework 7 can be used together.

Comment: Thank You. Let me know if you got any idea on how to make post request similar to $http.post where as in angular.